# Azure DevOps PR Trigger

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pull-request

When I create a PR from a branch named test(for example) a build is triggered but when I create a PR the build status is not taken under consideration. Is there any way I can enforce my PR (from all branches) to be validated with a build?

Here is my pipeline which is triggered correctly(it runs a Maven build):

```
trigger:
 branches:
  include:
    - '*'
  exclude:
    - develop
    - master
```

But at the end I have this:

[image: No build]

The build validation is missing.

Comment: Did you enable the build validation in the branch policies?

Comment: Only for master and develop. I cannot set it for any branch.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. when you want to enforce the build validation?

Comment: When I create a PR for my branch called test which is checked out from develop. If the build fails I don't want to be able to merge into develop.

Comment: So go the develop branch and enable the build validation on the branch policies

Comment: Now I got it. I though I should apply this validation the other way around. It is working. Thanks!

Comment: Great! you're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I had to go to develop and click branch policy and then add the build validation. Now the build validation appears for my PR where the target is develop.

Thanks a lot to Shayki Abramczyk!

[image: Build policy]